# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function, calling data from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

my addevent.ts:

```
export class EventPage {

eventDetail = {} as EventDetail;

eventDetailRef$: AngularFireList<EventDetail>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.eventDetailRef$ = this.database.list('event-list');
 }

addEvent( eventDetail: EventDetail) {

  this.eventDetailRef$.push({
  eventName: this.eventDetail.eventName,
  eventDesc: this.eventDetail.eventDesc,
  lat: Number(this.eventDetail.lat),
  lgt: Number(this.eventDetail.lgt)
  });

  this.eventDetail = {} as EventDetail;

  this.navCtrl.pop(); 

  }

}
```

my showevent.ts:

```
newEventListRef$ : AngularFireList<EventDetail>;
newEventList$: Observable<EventDetail[]>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private database: 
AngularFireDatabase) {
this.tabs=["New", "Upcoming"];
this.newEventListRef$ = this.database.list<EventDetail>('event-list');
this.newEventList$ = this.newEventListRef$.valueChanges();
}
```

my showevent.html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let new of newEventList$ | async">
      <h2>{{new.eventName}}</h2>
      <h4>{{new.eventDesc}}</h4>
      <h6>{{new.lat}}</h6>
      <h6>{{new.lgt}}</h6>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Problem: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

i can't call the data from the firebase, there is no redline or error in the VScode, i am very newb to ionic 3, pardon if i make the simplest mistakes.

Stack trace:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:78721:76)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:62701:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:26)
    at RefCountSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
    at Subject.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23237:25)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber._next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20786:26)
    at ConnectableSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:20750:18)
    at Notification.observe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:52585:50)
    at AsyncAction.DelaySubscriber.dispatch (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:81001:40)
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace of the error?

Comment: im sorry, ill edit it right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please upgrade `rxjs` in your project, also you have to include `rxjs-compat`. Try below command to do so:

```
npm i rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 promise-polyfill --save
```

Also you have to use subscribe while retrieving list data as follows:

```
this.database.list<EventDetail>('event-list').valueChanges().subscribe((eventData) => 
{ 
  console.log("eventDetails data", eventData);
},(err)=>{
   console.log("Error while retrieving eventDetails : ", err);
});
```